# Combining positions with inline-block elements to hover text over an image

Tags: css

I am trying to code a CSS-only fullscreen grid, and this is my code so far:

[JSFiddle Version](http://jsfiddle.net/5utCL/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS-Only Full-Screen Grid</title>
    <style>
    body { margin: 0; }
    .grid {
        line-height: 0;
    }
    .grid img {
        width: 20% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        vertical-align: top;
        position: relative;
    }
    .grid h2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <?php
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
            $hex = str_pad(dechex(mt_rand(0, 0xffffff)), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $hex2 = str_pad(dechex(mt_rand(0, 0xffffff)), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
            echo "<img src=\"http://placehold.it/640x480/" . $hex . "/" . $hex2 . "/\">";
            echo "<h2>Hello, World</h2>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I was happy with my code up until I tried adding text over the top of the images... setting a relative position to the images, with an absolute position to the headings actually stacks the `h2` in the top-left of the screen, where as I would like a `h2` over the top of each image.

Comment: Your link returns a blank JS Fiddle

Comment: Helps greatly if you save it! Amended.

Comment: You need wrap each image and associated h2 in a separate div that has `position:relative`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this looks the same: http://jsfiddle.net/5utCL/1/

Comment: @Paulie_D Your idea is correct though it needs minor tweaks and adjustments :)

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer is incomplete as it does not address the absolute positioning of the `h2` which is **required** and I have no idea where `width:32%` came from since they need to be 20% as stated in the original fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need wrap each image and associated h2 in a separate div that has position:relative

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/88RYw/2/)

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
.grid {
    line-height: 0;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 0; /* removes whitespace */

}
.grid img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;


}
.grid h2 {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    font-size:1rem; /* rest font-size */
}
.grid > div {
    width: 20%;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.grid > div img {
    display: block;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think this could work: (not tested). Not the nicest but if you have parent div with relative position, anything inside with absolute position can be easily positioned.. I think the reason it is not working in yours is that h2 (div with absolute position) is not wrapped inside div with relative position..

```
   <div class="grid">
            <?php
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
                $hex = str_pad(dechex(mt_rand(0, 0xffffff)), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
                $hex2 = str_pad(dechex(mt_rand(0, 0xffffff)), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    echo "<div style=\"position:relative\">";            
    echo "<img src=\"http://placehold.it/640x480/" . $hex . "/" . $hex2 . "/\">";
                echo "<div style=\"position:absolute\"><h2>Hello, World</h2></div>";
            }
            ?>
          </div>
   </div>
```

And you need to set position for h2 as desired..

Comment: You cannot put elements **inside** an image. Just doesn't work.

Comment: They are not inside an image, they are inside div with relative position that wraps the image...

Comment: I suggest you re-word this then - " I think the reason it is not working in yours is that h2 is not wrapped in img.."

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I have worked it out. I have made use of div's to stack them up.

This is the html I used:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/925e14/325111/" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/0524f3/ea01a8/" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/f688c8/ac9644/" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/9b7093/27948e/" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/78e101/2d96ab/" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/0b959c/b9a02f/" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/c7cea9/18c3a6/" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/684c16/dcccdf/" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/47352f/be1834/" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/b8f72a/fa074f/" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/13ccdf/9c765d/" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/71d393/15b698/" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/e080dd/a126a5/" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/dbf7be/9264d4/" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/3b2f96/dea622/" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/0cfab0/4b2fd8/" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/d27c64/1f4964/" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/8f1726/43b8ee/" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <h2>Hello, World</h2>

        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480/12421f/db44c1/" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and edited your CSS as follows:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
.grid {
    line-height: 0;
    width:100%;

}
.grid img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px !important;


}
.grid h2 {
    display:inline-block;
}
.grid > div {
    width: 32%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/88RYw/

This will just stretch the div's and the images when the window is resized. Alternatively, if you don't want that an instead want more div's to stack up when browser window is increased, then you will have to modify the  .grid > div as such:

```
.grid > div {
    width: 200px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This looks really good as images stack up based on the browser window width.

See this here: http://jsfiddle.net/gxzr3/

Hope this helps!!!